# How do GBM algorithms handle missing data?

Tags: xgboost, missing-data, lightgbm

How do algorithms GBM algorithms, such as XGBoost or LightGBM handle NaN values?
I know that they learn how to replace NaN values with other values but my question is: How do they do it exactly?

Comment: In short it creates a third branch as well for missing values and will automatically learn which direction to go when a value is missing, so when the data of a specific value is missing, it takes that direction. Refer https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754

Comment: What about lightGBM?

Answer (score 7):

**LIGHTGBM** will ignore missing values during a split, then allocate them to whichever side reduces the loss the most. https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2921

There are some options you can set such as usemissing=false, which disables handling for missing values. You can also use the zeroas_missing option to change behavior. [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/docs/Advanced-Topics.rst#missing-value-handle)

Comment: The link  which you provided http://mlexplained.com/2018/01/05/lightgbm-and-xgboost-explained/  for me is redirected to electronicsmarket.org - I don't know why